# Non-English Language Synonym Filter Factory for SOLR

Tags: search, solr, lucene, tomcat7, multilingual

I have been trying to use the synonym.txt file and the SynonymFilterFactory that ships out of the box with SOLR Lucene, with Indian Languages (Hindi for POC) but it doesn't seem to work as it works for English.

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27128070/solr-russian-synonyms-are-not-working?rq=1) here on stack overflow which raises a similar question but has no resolution, yet.

I have already taken care of the following to support Indian Language Search with SOLR,
1. Changed Browser Encoding to UTF-8
2. Added URIEncodings=UTF-8 in server.xml of Acapche Tomcat Server.

For the POC I have tried out the following things,
1. Created a new Field Type to support Hindi indexing,

```
<fieldType name="text_hi" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer> 
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <!-- normalizes unicode representation -->
    <filter class="solr.IndicNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
    <!-- normalizes variation in spelling -->
    <filter class="solr.HindiNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_hi.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.HindiStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

**UPDATE**
I also tried removing the stemming after going through the responses by @Mysterion and @Alexandre Rafalovitch on this post,

```
<fieldtype name="text_hi_rev" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" tokenizerFactory="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

2. Defined a new Field based on the created field type,
3. Added the following line to the synonyms.txt file,

   india,bharat,भारत , हिन्दुस्तान ,hindustan
4. Indexed the following strings as part different documents,

   मैं **भारत** का रहने वाला हूँ
   मैं **हिसंदुस्तान** का रहने वाला  हूँ 
   मैं **india** का रहने वाला हूँ
   मैं **hindustan** का रहने हूँ
   मैं **bharat** का रहने हूँ

**Expected Behaviour** : 
When I search for any of the keywords **india,bharat,भारत , हिन्दुस्तान ,hindustan** I should get all the documents indexed in Step-4

**Actual Behaviour**:
1. When searching with keywords **india, hindustan,or bharat** I get the following results,
मैं **india** का रहने वाला हूँ
मैं **hindustan** का रहने हूँ
मैं **bharat** का रहने हूँ

2. Searching with **भारत** returns the document with **भारत** ONLY and same with 
   **हिसंदुस्तान**

Any pointers if what I am trying is even possible? If possible, what could I be doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: synonyms.txt used to be written as " textfield=>txtfield,text,textfld,textfields,fieldtext" have you written it like that

Comment: @Swaraj, that's not required syntax sign =>  is for so called one way synonyms, if you just list them separated with comma it's okay as well

Comment: i've just answer previous question with russian synonyms, i also could test this for hindi

Comment: could you please clarify data in my test class?https://github.com/MysterionRise/octo-solr-adventure/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/mystic/NonEnglishSynonyms.scala it looks like i copy paste some symbols wrongly

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but could the Indic or Hindi normalization filters be modifying those terms into a form not identical to the one in "synonyms.txt"?

Comment: @swaraj, it can be written either ways. both ways have their own significance.

Comment: @femtoRgon, it is a possibility, but is there a way to actually test that?

Comment: @mysterion your test class looks flawless :) you can remove the"**" from the test strings

Comment: will test it tomorrow

Comment: @Mysterion, I have tried out stripping all filters from the type declaration, keeping the bare minimum, and yet the synonym search doesn't work. Please see Updated post for details

Comment: I've try to strip filters as well, and remove stars, but still not working, but it should

Comment: @Mysterion, it should, if it is working for Russian. What else could be going wrong? Is there any logs etc. we can check?

Comment: i'm still wondering if I copy data correctly

Comment: @Mysterion I just cracked it. It had to do with the Encoding of the synonym.txt file. I opened it with notepad and 'saved as' UTF-8 document. and it worked as expected. Thank You for all your help! You have been very kind.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of frustrating hours and help from @Mysterion, I accidentally stumbled upon the solution. Here are the two steps that led to the resolution,

1. As suggested by @Mysterion, swapped the synonym and stemming filters. Synonym filter should come before the stemming filters.
   2.Turned out, the synonym.txt file was not using the correct encoding. I opened the file in notepad, and saved it with UTF-8 encoding.
2. Restarted solr. Restarted tomcat.
3. Added new documents.
   5.Eureka!

Comment: glad it fixed right now, anyway i'm wondering why my test isn't working

Comment: Yes, even I am wondering the same. I see that the characters were copied   correctly.